# Dead Lock com SQL SERVER PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso gerar uma tabela de jogos para quatro grupos com 5 times, para cada dia um total de jogos deve ser realizados, na hora que a `PROCEDURE` que executa a inserção começa é chamada o banco entra em loop, alguém sabe onde está o erro?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insere_jogos (@grupoA VARCHAR(10), @grupoB VARCHAR(10), @date DATE, @saida VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT)
AS
DECLARE @codTeamA INT
DECLARE @codTeamB INT
DECLARE @validate VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE@count INT

SET @validate = 'FALSE'
SET @count = 1

WHILE(@validate != 'TRUE')
BEGIN
    WHILE(@count < 11)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            IF(@grupoA = 'grupoA')
            BEGIN
                SET @codTeamA = (SELECT codTeam FROM grupoA WHERE numTime = (CAST(RAND() * 5 AS INT)))
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF(@grupoA = 'grupoB')
                BEGIN
                    SET @codTeamA = (SELECT codTeam FROM grupoB WHERE numTime = (CAST(RAND() * 5 AS INT)))
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF(@grupoA = 'grupoC')
                    BEGIN
                        SET @codTeamA = (SELECT codTeam FROM grupoC WHERE numTime = (CAST(RAND() * 5 AS INT)))
                    END
                END
            END
            IF(@grupoB = 'grupoB')
            BEGIN
                SET @codTeamB = (SELECT codTeam FROM grupoB WHERE numTime = (CAST(RAND() * 5 AS INT)))
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF(@grupoB = 'grupoC')
                BEGIN
                    SET @codTeamB = (SELECT codTeam FROM grupoC WHERE numTime = (CAST(RAND() * 5 AS INT)))
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF(@grupoA = 'grupoD')
                    BEGIN
                        SET @codTeamB = (SELECT codTeam FROM grupoD WHERE numTime = (CAST(RAND() * 5 AS INT)))
                    END
                END
            END
            --END QUERY GET CODTEAM
            --BEGIN INSERT GAMES
            IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jogos) = 0)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO jogos(codTeamA, codTeamB, data_jogo) VALUES(@codTeamA, @codTeamB, @date)
                SET @count = @count + 1
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF((SELECT COUNT(@codTeamA) FROM jogos WHERE data_jogo = @date AND codTeamA = @codTeamA) = 0 
                    AND (SELECT COUNT(@codTeamB) FROM jogos WHERE data_jogo = @date AND codTeamB = @codTeamB) = 0)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO jogos(codTeamA, codTeamB, data_jogo) VALUES(@codTeamA, @codTeamB, @date)
                    SET @count = @count + 1
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    PRINT('TIME JÁ JOGOU HOJE')
                END
            END
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT('ERRO AO ADICIONAR JOGO')
        END CATCH
    END
    SET @validate = 'TRUE'
END

SET @saida = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: Não percebi totalmente a estrutura da SP, mas a variável `@count` apenas está a ser incrementada em dois casos, ficando outros dois de fora (`ELSE` e `CATCH`). Se por acaso entrar sempre num desses dois casos o `@count` nunca irá chegar aos 11 e entra num _loop_ infinito. Uma recomendação: evite utilizar `strings` no `WHILE`, use antes um `BIT`, visto que o valor é `TRUE` ou `FALSE`.